# Setting up Paho Javascript Client (MQTT) with mosquitto on AWS EC2 Ubuntu + Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mqtt, paho, ruby-mqtt

I have been trying to setup a MQTT broker on my AWS EC2 server, using the port 1883. So far it works with the [ruby-mqtt gem](https://github.com/njh/ruby-mqtt), but I am having trouble with setting it up with Paho Javascript Client for the website.

What I have done so far:

**Mosquitto**

Installed mosquitto on my AWS EC2 instance, and it is running and listening on port 1883. I subscribed to a topic locally using the command

```
mosquitto_sub -h localhost -p 1883 -v -t 'topic1'
```

**AWS EC2 Security Group**

Allow traffic over port 1883 (under tcp protocol)

**Ruby on Rails**

Installed ruby-mqtt gem, and tested the mqtt to be working by running the code below in rails console (development environment)

```
MQTT::Client.connect(ip_address_or_domain_name) do |c|
  c.publish('topic1', 'message to topic 1')
end
```

The message appears in the terminal where `mosquitto_sub` was running.

**Nginx**

All this was done without any configuration on Nginx configuration files.

**Paho Client**

So I fired up a local rails server on my local computer, and run the example javascript snippet on one of my html view.

```
// Create a client instance
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("mqtt.hostname.com", Number(1883), "", "clientId")

// set callback handlers
client.onConnectionLost = onConnectionLost;
client.onMessageArrived = onMessageArrived;

// connect the client
client.connect({onSuccess:onConnect});


// called when the client connects
function onConnect() {
  // Once a connection has been made, make a subscription and send a message.
  console.log("onConnect");
  client.subscribe("topic1");
  message = new Paho.MQTT.Message("Hello");
  message.destinationName = "topic1";
  client.send(message);
}

// called when the client loses its connection
function onConnectionLost(responseObject) {
  if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
    console.log("onConnectionLost:"+responseObject.errorMessage);
  }
}

// called when a message arrives
function onMessageArrived(message) {
  console.log("onMessageArrived:"+message.payloadString);
}
```

But I fail to connect. The error I am getting in the chrome developer console is:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://mqtt.example.com:1883/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

Im not sure what is wrong here. Greatly appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is Paho Javascript Client states that the parameter for `client` object has to be

> the address of the messaging server, as a **fully qualified WebSocket** URI, as a DNS name or dotted decimal IP address.

So making it listen to port 1883, which is the standard port for mqtt, will not work.

`ruby-mqtt` works as it is because it parameter is treated as a mqtt uri

In other words, `Paho` connects via `ws://host` while `ruby-mqtt` connects via `mqtt://host`. The latter connects to port 1883 with the correct protocol (not sure if this is the right word here) for the 
 correct port.

So `Paho` has to connect to another port where the websocket protocol can be used.

This is my solution.

**Mosquitto**

Version need to be at least 1.4 where websocket is supported. I add the last 3 lines to the default `mosquitto.conf` file.

```
# /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf
pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

port 1883

listener 1884
protocol websockets
```

This opens 2 ports for mosquitto to subscribe to over 2 different protocols respectively.

**AWS Security Group**

Allow traffic over port 1884 (under tcp protocol)

**Paho Client**

mqtt.hostname.com
change just the line where the client object is initialized to

```
client = new Paho.MQTT.Client("mqtt.hostname.com", Number(1884), "", "clientId")
```

Comment: Your mosquitto.conf is amazing!! Thx

Comment: :) Great I could be of help